# Performing arithmetic operations on hex-like string in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to write a perl one-liner which takes two hex-like strings (string that are look like hexadecimal, but without the leading 0x) and performs the arithmetic expression on the two hexadecimal strings.

For example.  Lets say I am reading the data from /proc/PID/maps.  The first column containing an address to memory in hexadecimal(without the leading 0x)

```
bff45000-bff66000
```

Is an example of the address.

The perl one-liner that I am using is:

```
perl -le 'print" "x5,"Hex\t\tDecimal\n","-"x15," "x5,"-"x15;foreach $a(@ARGV){$b=eval($a);printf"0x%-10x %17d\n",$b,$b}'
```

The problem I am having is that perl throws an error like this

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near...
```

This is because Perl can perform arithmetic operations on hexadecimal strings in the form of "0x... + 0x..." and not ".... + ....."

May someone please point me in the right direction as to how I may solve my problem please?

Comment: for curiosities sake and a challenge. Sure, I may use a script to parse the syntax properly, but maybe there is some Perl Monk out there who knows a few perl tricks to accomplish this without so much effor,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a perl oneliner, give the numbers the `0x` prefix and then just use `eval`:

```
echo "bff45000-bff66000" | perl -lne 's/([[:xdigit:]]+)/0x$1/g; print eval'
```

Outputs:

```
-135168
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the output in hex, too?

```
echo deadbeef-c00cc00c | perl -lne 's/[[:xdigit:]]+/hex($&)/g;printf "%x",eval'
```